# How to call javascript method at backend in asp.net and return the result

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I understand that javascript should be executed in front end. But in project I am working is using some JavaScript library which has further dependencies on jquery and other files. Now earlier we were executing code on front end. But as per Client request, we have to process at backend.
So basically I have some functions to execute in javascript,which unlike normally I can't execute on browser(not at least end user side) 
So how do i execute some javascript function at backend by giving it some input and then returning the result.
Any ideas guys?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Javascript runs in the browser, not the server. Do you mean you want to call the server from the client (passing some data), have the serer process the data and then return a result back to the client? (in which case you need ajax)

Comment: Yes I am aware that Javascript runs on browser not on server.Well yes pretty much ,except that code which I want to execute on server side has javascript function calls.

Comment: If you use Asp.Net you should try SignalR http://www.asp.net/signalr it's a library which allow calls in both ways

Comment: @StephenMuecke-I have edited the question

Comment: @Massanu-You mean that it using SignalR I can execute javascript under C# and process the result.

Comment: take a look to node.js, might provide what u need

Comment: You don't. You execute the code in `c#` (or what ever language you app is using and return the result.

Comment: I think, implementing "client callbacks" will help you.

Comment: You want to execute the javascript function from code behind right ?